# How can you Marry Mei without Wifi?

Tags: rune-factory

In [This Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/930701-rune-factory-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/47243) it says with the Tokimekatai fish required to marry Mei

> You also need to use the DS Wifi connection to level up the fish by trading it back and forth repeatedly with a friend

[This Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/930701-rune-factory-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/51707) also says something similar

> Trade the fish via wifi to raise its level. Reach at least 10+ levels.

What I am trying to do is reach a point where I can propose to any girl meaning I have met all their requirements. Given the fact that I have no friends (who play this game) I can't use the Wifi to trade the Tokimekatai fish.

Is there a way for me to level up the Tokimekatai fish to marry Mei without using wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to trade the fish in order to marry her, and with the end of friend code wireless support you will need to find a physical friend to assist you, or otherwise get access to another console and game to use locally.